# got warning No model artifact is saved under path /opt/ml/model. Your training job will not save any model files to S3. and no model deployed on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, amazon-sagemaker

```
n_user=20
n_item=100

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-M", "--model_dir", help="show model")
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", help="show model help")
args = parser.parse_args()
model_dir='/opt/ml/model'
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow
ncf_estimator = TensorFlow(  
    entry_point='ncf.py',
    role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),  
    train_instance_count=1,
    train_instance_type='ml.c5.2xlarge',  
    framework_version='2.1.0',  
    py_version='py3',  
    distributions={'parameter_server': {'enabled': True}},  
    hyperparameters={'epochs': 3, 'batch_size': 256, 'n_user': n_user, 'n_item': n_item},
)
```

I have the following code on Amazon Sagemaker and it is giving me error to define a model_dir, i tried different ways but failed please help me with that.

and the error when i train the model is:

```
2020-12-29 19:38:02,906 sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training WARNING  No model artifact is saved under path /opt/ml/model. Your training job will not save any model files to S3.
For details of how to construct your training script see:
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_tf.html#adapting-your-local-tensorflow-script
```

I have seen the docs but couldn't get anything.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? I am running into the same problem and I am trying to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the *script mode* of Sagemaker (meaning use an entry point such as *ncf.py*), you have to save your model by yourself and specifically at the following location **/opt/ml/model**. To get this path, you can use the environnement variable **SM_MODEL_DIR** that is defined when running ncf.py with sagemaker :

```
model_dir = os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR']
```

Then, save your model directly at /opt/ml/model with tensorflow such as  :

```
tf_model.save(model_dir)
```